# How can I get plotly Bar graph to group based on another column?

Tags: plotly, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd


challenge_count_df = pd.DataFrame({'Challenge': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
                                  'Count' : [32, 22, 40, 12, 10, 60, 32, 22, 44, 90],
                                  'Value' : ["0","5","10","15","5","10","5","10","15","10"],
                                  'Category' : [1,2,3,4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2]})
```

and I have the following code:

```
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': 'teal',
    "0":"silver",
    "10":"#FBEC5D",
    "5":"#50C878",
    "15":"#A23D60"
}


fig = go.Figure()
# create a bar graph with colors being different based on based on value but grouped by category
for t in challenge_count_df['Value'].unique():
    dfp = challenge_count_df[challenge_count_df['Value']==t]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['Challenge'],
                        y = dfp['Count'],
                        customdata=challenge_count_df['Category'],
                        name=t+" points",
                        marker_color=colors[t],
    ))

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

how can I make it that the bars would group up based on category? Everything else works. I just need to have the grouping to be based on the category column. Could someone please help direct me to the solution?

Comment: Your code has many issues, please fix them.

Comment: fixed the ones I could see. Sorry, I'm in a rush and was hoping to get a simple fix.

Comment: We will wait till you are not in a rush to fix the issues :)

Comment: I have no idea what else I have wrong

Comment: Run the above code and make it run and add the plot to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have python and the modules only on a server without a GUI. This is a sample dataframe. The original code is going to a plotly dash dashboard and is not connected to the internet. The rest of the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the current extraction criteria to categories and set the x-axis setting to list the columns you want to group. The resulting x-axis will be represented as multiple indices.

```
fig = go.Figure()

for t in challenge_count_df['Category'].unique():
    dfp = challenge_count_df[challenge_count_df['Category']==t]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=[dfp['Category'], dfp['Challenge']],
                          y=dfp['Count'],
                          width=0.75,
                          customdata=challenge_count_df['Category'],
                          name=str(dfp['Category'].values[0]),
                         )
                  )

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much! You are awesome.  I suppose I'll get dinged but it's nice to have someone that does this professionally and not think so highly of themselves that they demand to have a perfect example. I really appreciate you showing me how to do this!

Comment: could you show me though how to add the colors dict to using the marker variable so the colors of the bars are specific?

Comment: would it be something like this: 'marker_color=colors[dfp['Value'].values[0],'  ?

Comment: To set a different color for each bar, a little ingenuity is required. For example, if you want to have a similar color variation for each category, you need to prepare a multiple list created with two colors for Group 1, four colors for Group 2, and so on. The zip function will then be used to process the list in combination with the category variables. `color_list=[['34169e1','#91970'],['#ff7f50','#ff6347','#ff4500','#ff0000'],[...],[...]];for t, c in zip(challenge_count_df['Category'].unique(), color_list):`